# java Process блокировка потоков ввода/вывода

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, я создаю некий процесс

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(...);
procInl = builder.start();
```

Затем читаю информацию из него

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(procInl.getInputStream()));
Iterator itr = br.lines().iterator();
while( itr.hasNext() ) {
   itr.next();
}
```

Когда я дочитываю до последней строки процесс чтения блокируется в itr.hasNext(), насколько я мог понять это из-за того, что вся информация была прочитана и теперь работает поток записи (Это подтвердилось тем, что если закрыть поток записи в консоль

```
procInl.getOutputStream().close();
```

, то повисать в hasNext() не будет.

Или же читать следующим образом

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(procInl.getInputStream()));
while( br.ready() ) {
    a += (char)br.read();
}
```

Также читается без блокировки. Однако данных может быть много, поэтому мне нужен именно Stream

```
Iterator itr = br.lines().iterator();
```

для подгрузки при необходимости, например при прокрутке скролла.

Подскажите как избежать блокировки, не закрывая поток или может быть существует некое альтернативное решение?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решен. 
Пока я не закрою поток вывода, поток ввода не дойдёт до EOF.
Альтернативное решение: читать из из потока в файл, затем по мере надобности подгружать данные из файла.

Answer (score 1):

А вызываемый процес вообще завершается?
Например если запускать что-то через `cmd`, то `cmd` может остаться висеть в процессах с открытым `stdout`
А если процесс еще висит, но ничего не пишет, то `BufferedReader.ready()` вернет тебе `false`, т.к. буфер пустой и читать из него нечего.
.